# "Common mistake" tag or maybe "confusing words"?

Tags: feature-request

Here for example

[Differentiating between "written" and "writing"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8994/writing-or-writting)

I think I'm asking about common error(writing, but written). I was attacked, because I feel that some people think you should just remember it and don't think/ask why its that way. But that's ok, I don't mind(P.S. if you can make that question better, please do).

I think all users will benefit from common category/tag like "common-mistake" or "confusing words"(I'd like to get to know more common used words like that and I will thanks to the link given by VonC).

P.S. If you find any spelling errors here, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you didn't get "attacked" because you asked about a common error, but because of the way you phrased your question.

"Why is it *writing*, with one T, but *written*, with two?" is a perfectly valid question. However, "Why is *writing* spelled differently?" is not the best formulation of that thought. I actually tried to explain that in a comment on that question. Spelled differently from what? You must clarify. Now that you *have* clarified by editing the question, I don't think anyone will object to it.

My advice is: when asking a question, try to be as clear and specific as possible. If there's a particular reason why you're having a problem with a word, please specify that reason. Don't expect people to just guess it. They might guess it wrong, or they might not bother at all. And that won't help anybody.

The same is true of tags. Try to be as clear and specific as possible. If your question is about the spelling of the words *writing* and *written*, tag it with [spelling](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spelling) and [verbs](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/verbs). (You can be even more specific and add the tags [gerund](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gerund) or [participle](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/participle).) That will help people understand what your question is about *before they even click on it*.

The proposed tag [common-mistake](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/common-mistake), on the other hand, would not be clear or specific at all. First of all, the term "common" is not clearly defined and is highly subjective. (For example, I have never encountered the misspelling *writting* before. For all I can tell, it's the exact opposite of common.) Secondly, it doesn't really tell us what the question is about. It could be about verbs or nouns; single words or complete phrases; spelling or pronunciation; etymology or punctuation; we really can't tell. It's a so-called "meta" tag, and such tags are expressly discouraged across the entire StackExchange network. As Jeff Atwood [puts it](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/):

> **From this point on, meta-tagging is explicitly discouraged.**
>
> How can you tell you’re using a meta-tag? It’s easier than you might think.
>
> 1. **If the tag can’t work as the only tag on a question, it’s probably a meta-tag.** Every tag you use should be able to work, more or less, as the only tag on a question. Meta-tags, like [beginner], [subjective], and [best-practices], are useless by themselves — they tell you nothing at all about the content of the question.
> 2. **If the tag commonly means different things to different people, it’s probably a meta-tag.** In a cruel, ironic twist, the meaning of the tag [subjective] itself … is actually subjective. Ditto for [best-practices] and [beginner]. Best practices to whom? Beginner by what criteria? These tags are impossible to define by anything remotely resembling an objective metric.

The tag [common-mistake](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/common-mistake) clearly meets *both* of the above criteria. I would oppose introducing it.